# EF query with join is not running

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Hi I have query in entity framework, but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

I need this result

```
SELECT id, min(price) minPrice
    FROM (
        SELECT id, max(servicePrice) msi FROM offers
            GROUP BY id
        ) as mvo INNER JOIN offers so ON mvo.id=so.id AND mvo.msi=so.servicePrice
    WHERE so.id=o.id
    GROUP BY so.id
```

I tried following code, but there are two errors. Join returns `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.`. And last select works correctly when there isn't `minPrice = ms.Min(s => s.price)`. When I have min function there, runtime returns `System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'`

```
var q = 
    from vo in dataContext.Offers join so in (
        from o in dataContext.Offers
            group o by o.id into oo
            select new { id = oo.Key, MaxSI = oo.Max(v => (v.servicePrice)) }
    ) on new { vo.id, vo.servicePrice } equals new { so.id, so.MaxSI }
        group vo by vo.id into ms
        select new { id = ms.Key, minPrice = ms.Min(s => s.price) }
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the join should be like this -

```
var q = 
    from vo in dataContext.Offers join so in (
        from o in dataContext.Offers
            group o by o.id into oo
            select new { id = oo.Key, MaxSI = oo.Max(v => (v.servicePrice)) }
    ) 
    on new { id = vo.id, price = vo.servicePrice } equals new { id = so.id, price = so.MaxSI }
    group vo by vo.id into ms
    select new { id = ms.Key, minPrice = ms.Min(s => s.price) }
 ;
```

Comment: Nice thanks, `id =` is a solution for join. Do you have any idea, why `, minPrice = ms.Min(s => s.price)` return error `System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'`?

Comment: Have you tried setting QuickWatch to debug the query?